# How to really generate c# / java code with the Drakon Diagram Editor?

Tags: java, c#, drakon, drakon-editor

Drakon editor seems nice http://java.dzone.com/announcements/drakon-editor-19-support-java
but after reading the doc http://drakon-editor.sourceforge.net/csharp.pdf
I still don't understand how one can generate c# or java code ? In the menu there is only export to pdf or png.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used DRAKON but I just installed it and it looks like the tutorial you referenced in the question ends before selecting *DRAKON > Generate Code* from the menu.

[image]

This opens the form which will generate the code for you (just make sure you follow all of the steps from the tutorial first to avoid errors).